# Why do all keys start being interpreted as "." in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, putty

I am running Emacs on a unix server, which I access using PuTTY. Occasionally, I accidentally type some combination of keystrokes that causes all future input to be interpreted as a period. I'm pretty sure this always starts when I'm in Emacs, but it continues after exiting (ctrl-xc still works), so if I exit and try to enter something at the prompt it just looks like "....".

I have no idea what I'm doing that causes this. Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds more likely to be an issue with the terminal/PuTTY than with Emacs. It may be that the terminal is intercepting some key combination which you use in Emacs but not elsewhere, and that is why it only seems to happen in Emacs.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was confused about how Emacs could affect the rest of the terminal session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with phils comment to the question. But In emacs whenever you like to see what you have just pressed, There is a <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> which gives you the history of keystrokes